# What will happen if I skip waiting[i] = false In the following snippet of code?

Tags: c, operating-system, synchronization, deadlock

The code below is designed to solve critical section problem. Given that there are N processes that are modifying a common data-structure in their critical section.

These are the Data Structure Used:

```
boolean waiting[n];
boolean lock;
```

Here is the testAndSet() function that is assumed to execute atomically due to hardware support.

```
boolean TestAndSet(boolean *target) 
{
    boolean rv = *target;
   *target = TRUE;
    return rv;
}
```

// The following code ensures mutual-exclusion

```
do {
    waiting[i] = TRUE;
    key = TRUE;

    while (waiting[i] && key)
        key = TestAndSet(&lock);

    waiting[i] = FALSE;  //what if I skip this??

    // critical section

    j = ( i + 1) % n ;
    while((j != i) && ! waiting[j])
    {
       j = (j + 1) % n ;
    }
    if (j == i)
       lock = FALSE;
    else
       waiting[j] = FALSE;

   //remainder section

   }while (TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to indent the line after the first while.

The stuff below the "// critical section" will unlock the next task waiting for access, or release the lock if nobody is waiting.

If you don't clear your waiting flag, then another task (presumably running the same code around their access to protected memory) who already had the lock will think you're still waiting and will clear your waiting flag for you to allow you to run (assuming you're sitting in the loop, checking TestAndSet, the only place your wait flag is true).  And it keeps the lock flag set, since it's just passing the lock on to you effectively.  But if your code has actually moved on from that point without setting the value false, then you can't get back to the TestAndSet without setting your waiting flag to True, and since lock is also left at true, then this task can't run, and other tasks aren't running because the next task in line wasn't given the go-ahead (or lock wasn't set to false), and the whole system is now gummed up.

Comment: Also, since the only place there might be a memory barrier here is within whatever implementation of `TestAndSet` is being used, there's possibly a number of fun little things to tease out on multi-processor multi-cache systems with less than strict cache coherency constraints... In particular `waiting[J] = FALSE` may take (relatively speaking) quite some time to be noticed by other CPUs... Or at least it will cause cache line bouncing and associated performance degradation...

Comment: @Nerf Lets suppose we have 2 Process A and B. A Acquired the lock and completed its critical section and then didn't set waiting[A] to false. Now Executes B. Seeing lock released, It will acquire the lock and will execute into its critical section. Now the code after critical section executes in process B. It will stop when Index reaches to A. Now it will set Waiting[A]=false.
2 Possibilities exists now 
1)Either A was waiting for lock in while loop. In this case the wait will be over for A.
2)Or A is executing remainder section, In this case setting waiting[A] to false will have no Impact.

Comment: Possibility 1) is okay, but for 2) it will have an impact.  First if there's a Process C that was legitimately waiting, its turn might be skipped.  Even without C, A can't get back to the while loop without setting Waiting[A]=true. Since lock wasn't set to false, now A will wait forever in the TestAndSet loop.  Same thing for everybody else.

Comment: This is why the counting semaphore was created.  Keep this code in the OS so a programmer doesn't accidentally make a mistake, breaking all the tasks with something that might be very hard to duplicate.

Comment: Thx for the comment and checking it as an answer. :) At first I thought you were just a student looking for an answer to copy onto homework, but I see you were taking this seriously, so I'm glad I answered

Answer (score 0):

If you skip the '... = FALSE' line that would mean that you are still waiting to acquire lock (critical section) in a first while loop (for specific i) and would break the logic of "round robin" access to critical section in the second while loop.

Comment: I still can't get it. An example would be very helpful.

Comment: The second while loop gives anyone who set waiting flag to TRUE ownership over critical section in a circular manner (round robin) without reacquiring lock. If no one is waiting the lock is released. Not sure i can give you simple exmple.

Comment: Keep in mind all n tasks are running the same code.  So the other tasks will see this task as still waiting when it really isn't. It's some other task releasing its lock and deciding who runs next that actually creates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating that line would probably break the whole thing. The two lines immediately above it are a `while` loop which may terminate on one of two conditions - either `waiting[i]` becoming false, or `key` becoming false (or maybe both "simultaneously"). If the loop terminates due to `key` being false, then `waiting[i]` is presumably still true, so you would get into a condition where you both hold the lock and simultaneously think you are still waiting for the lock, which probably violates the preconditions for the subsequent `while` loop...

Comment: Yes In theory it will not be ethical if we skip that step as waiting[i]==true means ith process wants to access critical section  but still please revert if you can think of any practical example.

Comment: A practical example for breaking memory protection?

Comment: If for certain "i" two first assignments to waiting[i] would be removed you might have something like "allow all in queue once and wait for me again".

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. The whole confusion is created by do while() loop which encloses the whole code. Instead of this do while() thing, if These were like some function representing a process such as

```
function(int i)
{
  waiting[i] = TRUE;
  key = TRUE;

  while (waiting[i] && key)
    key = TestAndSet(&lock);

  waiting[i] = FALSE;  //what if I skip this??

  // critical section

  j = ( i + 1) % n ;

  while((j != i) && ! waiting[j])
  {
    j = (j + 1) % n ;
  }

  if (j == i)
   lock = FALSE;
  else
   waiting[j] = FALSE;

  //remainder section
}
```

lets say a function is called with i = 3 (say process i3.  for N = 5). And this process i3  is never executed again then not setting waiting[3]=false will end up in deadlock situation. As process i4 may think that process i3 wants to run thus it will end up by setting waiting[3] = false and not releasing the lock